# A seemingly impossible combinatorics problem!

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, contest-math, combinations

The problem:

If n, m equally spaced straight lines, mutually perpendicular to each other, bounds a rectangle, in which another rectangle is chosen and shaded with a minimum side length of $[\frac{n}{2}], [\frac{m}{2}]$. Then:

(a) How many rectangles can be chosen in the larger rectangle so that none of them coincide / contain the shaded rectangle?

(b) Probability of choosing a rectangle which contains both the shaded rectangle and at least one unshaded rectangle?
*([.] - is the greatest integer function)*

These are my efforts on the problem:

1. I found out that the bigger rectangle has $\frac{n(n-1)m(m-1)}{4}$ possible rectangles to choose from.
2. Taking a simpler case in which the inner rectangle, fixed at one of the vertices with the smaller rectangle bounded by i, j lines I used the above formula to get $$\frac{m(m-1)(n-i)(n-i-1) + n(n+1)(m-j-1)}{4} - \frac{(n-i)(n-i-1)(m-j)(m-j-1)}{4}$$ 
   (Correct me if I’m wrong)

But, how do i find all possible ways? This is the point where i was stumped.

Please suggest a method to solve this question using only *high school* level combinatorics, any help would be appreciated.

(*Note*: This is a slightly generalised question asked in the real problem so there may be some mistakes and the title is based on what I felt!)

Comment: This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.

Comment: How about counting the rectangles that do **not** intersect? Pay attention to not double-count the rectangles contained completely in the four "corner rectangles".

Comment: Yeah, that’s something that I worked on, but how do I keep track of all possible ways in an efficient way?

Comment: @TanmayGajapati The number of intersecting and non-intersecting rectangles not only depends on the lengths of the sides of the shaded rectangle but also on its position inside the big rectangle.

Comment: I'm not that sure but does it mean that we need to use some dort of double summations?... If yes, please elobrate.

Comment: All right, I'll try. Please note for this website: If you comment a post that isn't from a specific user (like me) without mentioning that specific user (with the @ character like in @TanmayGajapati), that specific user won't get notified about your comment.

Comment: Please clarify: What are you trying to count in your "simpler case"? What are "inner rectangle" and "smaller rectangle"? You seem to count rectangles that do not **intersect** with another rectangle, but how does this relate to "**coincide/contain**"? I guess that your formula should have looked like $$\binom{m}{2}\binom{n-i}{2}+\binom{n}{2}\binom{m-j}{2}-\binom{n-i}{2}\binom{m-j}{2}$$ Also: what exactly is an "unshaded rectangle"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have already found out, the total number of possible *shaded* rectangles is
$$
\frac{n(n-1)m(m-1)}{4}=\binom{n}{2}\binom{m}{2}
$$
To see this, note that for the boundaries of a possible *shaded* rectangle, we can independantly choose $2$ of the one group of $n$ parallel straight lines (let's denote them as "vertical") and $2$ of the other (perpendicular) group of $m$ parallel lines (let's call them "horizontal").

A specific *shaded* rectangle is uniquely defined by its "distances" from the outermost vertical and horizontal lines. Let's denote these with $l$ and $r$ ("left" and "right") for the vertical and $t$ and $b$ ("top" and "bottom") for the horizontal boundaries. Clearly, if the selected rectangle is non-degenerated, $l+r<n-1$ and $t+b<m-1$.

First, let's count the number of "outer" rectangles that coincide/contain our specific *shaded* rectangle. For such an "outer" rectangle, we have $l+1$ choices for the left boundary, $r+1$ choices for the right boundary, $t+1$ choices for the top boundary and $b+1$ choices for the bottom boundary. Therefore, the number of "outer" rectangles is $(l+1)(r+1)(t+1)(b+1)$, and so the number of possible rectangles that do **not** coincide/contain our *shaded* rectangle is
$$
\binom{n}{2}\binom{m}{2}-(l+1)(r+1)(t+1)(b+1)
$$
Assuming that an "*unshaded*" rectangle is a rectangle that is not contained in (or equals) the *shaded* rectangle, then all rectangles that contain/coincide the *shaded* rectangle, except the *shaded* rectangle itself, also contain an *unshaded* rectangle, so the desired probability is
$$
p=\frac{(l+1)(r+1)(t+1)(b+1)-1}{\binom{n}{2}\binom{m}{2}}
$$

Comment: Thank you for providing the solution.

Comment: @TanmayGajapati Thank you, too, it was fun. I have chosen this "LRTB representation" of the rectangles, because this way, you can immediately see the symmetry of the counting formula. :-)